# Как в объекте js обратиться к его значению?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код, нужно сразу, автоматически определять и сохранять в этот же объект результат вычисления widthPost / heightPost, но как обратится в этом объекте к его значениям?

```js
var infPost = {
  widthPost: '1',
  heightPost: '1',
  proportionsPost: widthPost / heightPost
}
```

Comment: сразу так и не получится)

Comment: @thisman, а как сделать, чтобы получилось?

Comment: `var infPost = {
  widthPost: 10,
  heightPost: 2,
  get proportionsPost() { return this.widthPost / this.heightPost }
}`